# Как поставить like в VK?

Tags: java, android, vkontakte-api, like

Задача: надо поставить лайк под записью. Пишу вот этот код:

```
final int item_id = 79719;
final String type = "post";
final String owner_id = "-123695926";
final double vers = 5.60;

setLike(type, owner_id, item_id, vers); // запускаю метод
```

Сам метод:

```
public static String setLike(String type, String owner_id, int item_id, double vers) {
    final String[] res = {""};
    VKRequest request = new VKRequest(
        "likes.add",
         VKParameters.from("type", type, "owner_id", owner_id, "item_id", item_id, "version", vers)
        );

    request.executeSyncWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
            super.onComplete(response);
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = response.json.getJSONObject("response");
                res[0] = jsonObject.getString("likes");
                System.out.print("qwerty"+jsonObject);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }}
    });
    return res[0];
}
```

Переменные (их значения) в метод переходят, но запись не лайкается

Подскажите в чём проблема?

Comment: `в метод переходят` - и что выводит `System.out.print("qwerty"+jsonObject);` ?

Comment: выводит значенике: null

Comment: поэтому и не лайкается. потому что видимо запрос неправильный

Comment: а какой правильный?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setLike("post", "-5024****", post.id);`

Надо указать:

-"post" лайк ставиться в пост

-группу где приходит пост

-и id  с VKApiPost post